# R shiny dynamic UI add column to tibble

Tags: r, shiny

Please see below picture for illustration and reproducible code attached at the bottom.

I have 3 textInput, called `Urgency 1`, `Urgency 2`, `Urgency 3`. And I have 1 uiOutput that will create extra `Modality Name` based on the number input from `Number of modalities`. The Tibble's 3rd, 4th, 5th, columns (named as `2WW`,`Urgent`,`Routine`), those names are based on the input from `Urgency 1`, `Urgency 2`, `Urgency 3`. So far, it's good.

What I want also is, when the number of modalities become 2, there will be 3 extra columns added to the tibble after column 5, and they will be named as `2WW2`,`Urgent2`,`Routine2`, which makes the tibble now have 8 columns in total. And when the number of modalities become 3, there will be 3 more extra columns named as `2WW3`,`Urgent3`,`Routine3`, and so on. Of course, the name of `2WW2`,`Urgent2`,`Routine2`, of which `2WW`,`Urgent`,`Routine` come from the input from `Urgency 1`, `Urgency 2`, `Urgency 3` as well.

It's not just about adding extra 3 columns when the number of modalities changes, but also the relevant columns should disappear if the number of modalities reduces.

[image: pic1]

```
library(shiny)
library(purrr)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("No_modalities", label = "Number of modalities",
                   value = 1, min = 1, max = 100, step = 1),
      textInput("urgency1", label = "Urgency 1", value = "2WW"),
      textInput("urgency2", label = "Urgency 2", value = "Urgent"),
      textInput("urgency3", label = "Urgency 3", value = "Routine"),
      uiOutput("modality"),
      width = 3
    ),
    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput("template"),
      textOutput("check")
      , width = 9
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  modality_names <- reactive(paste0("Modality ", seq_len(input$No_modalities)))
  output$modality <- renderUI({
    map(modality_names(), ~ textInput(.x, label = paste(.x," Name"),
                                      value = isolate(input[[.x]])))
  })
  
  df1 = reactive({
    tibble(Column1 = rep(1,10), Column2 = rep(2,10),
           !!input$urgency1 := "",
           !!input$urgency2 := "",
           !!input$urgency3 := "")
  })
  
  output$template = renderDataTable({
    df1()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attempts, I've managed to solve the problem now. I tried to break the problem into smaller pieces first, for example, how can I combine a list of strings with the seq_len to make sure the column names can respond to the input$No_modalities. Here's my solution. I used the `reactable` package for displaying the datatable.

[image: pic1]

```
library(shiny)
library(reactable)
library(tidyverse)


ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("No_modalities", label = "Number of modalities",
                   value = 1, min = 1, max = 100, step = 1),
      textInput("urgency1", label = "Urgency 1", value = "2WW"),
      textInput("urgency2", label = "Urgency 2", value = "Urgent"),
      textInput("urgency3", label = "Urgency 3", value = "Routine"),
      uiOutput("modality"),
      width = 3
    ),
    mainPanel(
      reactableOutput("template"),
      textOutput("check")
      , width = 9
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  modality_names <- reactive(paste0("Modality ", seq_len(input$No_modalities)))
  
  output$modality <- renderUI({
    map(modality_names(), ~ textInput(.x, label = paste(.x," Name"),
                                      value = isolate(input[[.x]])))
  })
  
  df1 = reactive({
    tibble(Column1 = rep(1,10), Column2 = rep(2,10))
  })
  
  # columns to add
  columnsToAdd = reactive({
    c(outer(c(input$urgency1,input$urgency2,input$urgency3),
            seq_len(input$No_modalities), paste0))
  })

  df2 = reactive({add_column(df1(),!!!set_names(as.list(rep(1,
                                                      length(columnsToAdd()))),
                            nm=columnsToAdd()))})
    
  output$template = renderReactable({
      reactable(df2())
    })


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```